# How to read characteristics in background BLE using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm developing app which reads specific characteristics in the background mode. Can this be achieved in the background with selecting the background mode as `"Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories"` in the plist. Is there any chances of rejecting the app in background if we read particular characteristics of a known service? Reading the characteristics should happen continuously. If we `setNotify to "True"` will this work in the background. Please provide some valuable suggestions/work around if anyone is aware of it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

1. *Can this be achieved in the background with selecting the background mode as "Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories" in the plist.*

Yes you can definitely read ble characteristics when your app is in background mode setting the “Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories” background mode in the capabilities tab

2. *Is there any chances of rejecting the app in background if we read particular characteristics of a known service?*

If your app needs ble background mode and correctly declares it in the capabilities tab, the app won’t be rejected

3. *Reading the characteristics should happen continuously. If we setNotify to "True" will this work in the background*

In order to get notified each time the ble characteristic of your ble peripheral changes its value, you can correctly [setNotify](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518949-setnotifyvalue) to true on the desired characteristic. Each time the characteristic changes its value the [peripheral(_:didUpdateStateFor:Error)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheraldelegate/1518708-peripheral) callback will be triggered and you can get the updated value. Setting the background mode correctly, this callback will be triggered even if your application is in background and your phone is locked.

Comment: It is working :) I have added the code and tested in my device. Value gets notified even when mobile is locked :D

Answer (score 0):

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                    error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }

        for characteristic in characteristics {
            print(characteristic)
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")

                peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
            }
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                    error: Error?)
 {

```
    print("characteristic: ", characteristic)

    guard let string = String(bytes: characteristic.value!, encoding: .utf8) else {
        return
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Capabilities -> On Background Modes -> Select External accessory communication & Uses Bluetooth LE accessories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk2JW.png)